# Problems with sign-ins and opening my question

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I can't open my question, other questions I can. And I have trouble signing in here and on PC. on Pc it constantly says I need to complete the signup or that I have to log in again to use this account etc., and here I don't see my profile, my picture, nor my name.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-D855

  - OS Version: 5.0 (1446038723)

Comment: [Your problem should be fixed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287971/how-can-a-user-be-a-member-of-the-same-community-twice#comment934584_287971)