# How can a user be a member of the same community twice?

Tags: bug, status-completed, multiple-accounts, communities-list

[This user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/345955/martina) appears to belong to English Language & Usage twice.  How can this be?  Is this a botched account merger?

> [image: Meta User]
>
> [image: iOS App]

Comment: Happens when an account merge fails. Just needs a dev to clean it up is all. Usually the user will contact us about it because it pretty much destroys their ability to use the account in the process.

Comment: @animuson looks like the same user is already experiencing what you anticipated at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287970/215590